# Regular Expression for multiple folder names in URL and Excluded Extension Flags

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm processing multiple js files to build bundles via webpack. However I need to target multiple js files to process across multiple folders, while being able to exclude js files with certain flags in the filename.

I have the following files:

```
/styles/portal/version2/libraries/jquery.js
/styles/portal/version2/libraries/library.exclude.js
/styles/portal/version2/components/componenta.js
/styles/portal/version2/konstructs/konstructa.js
/styles/portal/version2/konstructs/konstructb.js
/styles/portal/version2/konstructs/konstructc.js
/styles/portal/version2/konstructs/konstructd.disabled.js
/styles/portal/version2/vendors/vendor.js
/styles/portal/version2/vendors/vendor.exclude.js
```

And this should only grab the following files to bundle:

```
/styles/portal/version2/libraries/jquery.js

/styles/portal/version2/konstructs/konstructa.js
/styles/portal/version2/konstructs/konstructb.js
/styles/portal/version2/konstructs/konstructc.js

/styles/portal/version2/vendors/vendor.js
```

So essentially any .js file out of the specific **libraries**, **konstructs**, **vendor** folders and then don't include anything with **disabled.js** or **exclude.js**

Comment: A single regex would be terribly cluttering to do this (not to mention maintaining) . How does your bundle engine work? Is it Javascript? If so, you'd be better off writing some code and implementing a dictionary-like structure to filter the files.

Comment: Would the regex be for inclusion or exclusion ? Because if using exclusion, it might miss something. Is it better to be %100 sure using just inclusions or less sure using exclusions ?

Comment: @EricWu I'm writing this for a glob match pattern for webpack entry point

Comment: @x15 The files grabbed are for inclusion so include only those in librarires/konstructs/vendors, and that don't have the disabled.js or exclude.js file extensions

Answer (score 2):

To get the three directories *`libraries, konstructs or vendors`* that contain
non-*`disabled`* nor *`exclude`* in the file name parts of *`.js`* files would be this:

`/^.*?\/(?:libraries|konstructs|vendors)(?=\/)(?:[^\/.]*\/)*(?![^\/]*?\b(?:disabled|exclude)(?=\.)[^\/]*?\.js$)[^\/]*?\.js$/gm`

https://regex101.com/r/rTUfeQ/1

Note, use the multi-line modifier if looking at multi-line strings.
If not, no need for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try ***exclude*** option in [rule-condition](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-conditions) with this pattern

```
/\.(exclude|disabled)\.js$/
```

- `\.` - Matches `.`
- `(exclude|disabled)` - Match `exclude` or `disabled` word
- `\.js` - Matches `. followed by js`
- `$`  - End of string

Comment: So that solves the exclusion of the disabled.js & exclude.js types, how would I solve for konstructs, libraries, vendors folder requirements ?

Comment: You misspelled `disabled` in the regex code. Can't edit: less than 6 characters :man-facepalming:

Comment: @SethDuncan those you can consider those in test or include, something like. `/(konstructs|vendor)\.js$/`